# Can I define Global Variables across Build Definitions in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines

In VSTS it is possible to create variables per build definition as per the Microsoft documentation

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables

Is it possible to define global variables that I can use across multiple build definitions?

Scenario:

I have a variable 'MyPassword' that is used in multiple definitions. If I want to change the value of 'MyPassword' I have to do it in each build definition rather than just in one global variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is added to vsts.

Old awnser: This is no possible at this moment. It seems a nice feature. I'll user voice item for this.

uservoice: [14515326-project-level-build-release-variables](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14515326-project-level-build-release-variables)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can using Variable Groups in the Release & Release/Library option
[enter link description here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/more-release-definition#release-definition-variables-and-variable-groups)

Comment: Please have a look at your answer; you probably want to edit it.

Comment: That's related to Releases, not Builds unfortunately